# Is it possible to implement theme preprocessor on specific template in drupal 8?

Tags: theming, hooks

What I am here trying to achieve is simple. I want to change the default drupal "submitted by" field to only render day and date but not the time when the node was created. To do so I want to preprocess the field which is being evoked by field.html.twig. But apparently, I don't want to run the preprocess on every field by using hook suggestion "field". Hence i created the specific template "field--default--node--node-submitted-by--blogs.html.twig". Now I want to implement theme preprocessor on this specific template. Can achieve on based on template suggestions or not?If so how?

Answer (score 0):

If you implemented your own template suggestion then it's as easy as writing a function with the following name:

```
function THEME_OR_MODULE_NAME_preprocess_field__default__node__node_submitted_by__blogs(&$variables) {
}
```

The main thing to take care of is to convert the hyphen characters (-) to underscores (_).

Good luck!

Comment: Ur welcome. If this is the right answer indeed, you should mark it for reference.